# Extract highlighted text in R from docx to excel

Tags: r, excel, extract

Is there a way to extract subsets of highlighted texts under headers in a word docx to a dataframe in R?

I have a set of word documents with the following headers PID, X, and Y, under PID there is a 6 character identifier, under X there is a series of words, some of which are highlighted, under Y there is a different series of words with some words highlighted. Only the highlighted words need to be extracted.

The resulting excel should have PID, X, Y as columns. Each PID should have corresponding values in X and Y that were from the same docx. Any ideas are appreciated!

Example word doc:

[image]

|PID   | X          | Y
|AD9212| rice, bread| red

I tried docx_summary but no formatting information is extracted.

Comment: Have you tried reading the xml file of the docx?

Answer (score 0):

As @guasi proposed, you can take the route via HTML (saving your document as `.htm`). That way, the highlighted sections will be enclosed in `<span mso-highlight=...>` tags which you can, e.g. harvest with {rvest}, using CSS selectors, like so:

```
library(rvest)

paras <- read_html('text.htm') |>
  ## get word paragraphs via CSS selectors:
             html_nodes('body p') |>
  ## remove empty paras:
  Filter(f = \(para) html_text(para) != '')

## get PID from para following para containing 'PID':
PID  <- paras[grep('PID', paras) + 1] |>
  html_text() 

## get highlighted items:
highlights <- 
    paras[grep('X|Y', paras) + 1] |>
    Map(f = \(para) para |>
                  html_nodes('[style*=mso-highlight]') |>
                  html_text() |>
                  paste(collapse = ', ')
             )

## name and convert to data frame:
c(PID, highlights) |>
  setNames(nm = c('PID', 'X', 'Y')) |>
  list2DF()
```

```
     PID           X   Y
1 AD9212 rice, bread red
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The processing will depend on the detailed internal structure of the Word document and since we don't have that, for reproducibility, we will use the test Word document generated in the Note at the end.  It uses the officer package to generate the test Word document as a series of paragraphs.

Now given that document get the `officer::docx_summary` data frame, `ds`. The row numbers after the X and Y elements in `ds$text`
are also the paragraph numbers, `ix`, of the X and Y values so
form an xpath expression which looks for those paragraph numbers and in those paragraphs get the w:r tags having a w:color tag as those w:r tags have the desired text content.  Put that text into the text column and then reform that column into a 3 column matrix and then a data frame, `DFout`. Finally write that out to an Excel file.

```
library(officer)
library(xml2)
library(writexl)

doc <- read_docx(File)  # File & file itself defined in Note at end
ds <- docx_summary(doc)

# get only X and Y text values with color & put in text
ix <- which(ds$text == "X" | ds$text == "Y") + 1
xp <- sprintf('//w:p[%d]//w:r[.//w:color]', ix)
ds$text[ix] <- sapply(xp, \(xp) xp |>
  xml_find_all(doc$doc_obj$get(), xpath = _) |>
  xml_text() |>
  toString()
)

# convert text column to data frame with PID, X, Y columns
DFout <- ds$text[seq(2, nrow(ds), 3)] |>
  matrix(nc = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("PID", "X", "Y"))) |>
  as.data.frame()

DFout
##      PID                X      Y
## 1 AD9212      rice, bread    red
## 2 AD9213 riceroni, breads redish

Fileout <- sub("\\.docx$", ".xlsx", File)
write_xlsx(DFout, Fileout)
```

**2)** An alternative is to use xpath to extract PID, X, Y, and the highlighted words and then reform that into DCF format, a matrix and then a data frame.  `doc` is from above.

```
library(officer)
library(xml2)

xp <- '(//w:t[../../preceding-sibling::*[1]//text() = "PID"]|
        //w:t[..//w:color]|
        //w:t[text() = "PID" or text() = "X" or text() = "Y"])
      '
txt <- xml_find_all(doc$doc_obj$get(), xp) |> xml_text()

dcf <- sapply(txt, function(x) if (x == "PID") paste0("\n", x, ":")
  else if (x == "X" || x == "Y") paste0(x, ":") 
  else paste0("  ", x))

dcf |>
  textConnection() |>
  read.dcf() |>
  apply(2, chartr, old = "\n", new = " ") |>
  as.data.frame()
##      PID               X      Y
## 1 AD9212      rice bread    red
## 2 AD9213 riceroni breads redish
```

### Note

```
library(officer)

File <- "user23518192_test.docx"

red <- fp_text(color = "red")
Block_List <- block_list(
  fpar("PID"),
  fpar("AD9212"),
  "",
  fpar("X"),
  fpar("Chicken ", ftext("rice",  red), " pizza ", ftext("bread",  red)),
  "",
  fpar("Y"),
  fpar("Green ", ftext("red", red), " pink"),
  "",
  fpar("PID"),
  fpar("AD9213"),
  "",
  fpar("X"),
  fpar("Chickens ", ftext("riceroni",  red), " pizzas ", ftext("breads",  red)),
  "",
  fpar("Y"),
  fpar("Greenish ", ftext("redish", red), " pinkish")
)
word_doc <- read_docx() |> body_add(Block_List)

print(word_doc, File)
```